# SSIS executing chained stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql-server, asynchronous, ssis, async-await

I'm struggling around a SSIS Package which i want to execute.
It's all about that i'm executing stored procedure from which i'm getting all the reminders i want and start looping over them with `SqlDataReader` as i'm looping over the reminders i'm sending email or sms depending on the type of the reminder and if the result of the sending of the email or the sms is succesful i'm deleting the reminder. The problem here is that when i execute the Package it only send sms/email and not deleting the reminder. I'm applying the code with the that puzzels me

```
        public async void Main()
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("..."))
        {
            List<ReminderData> reminders = new List<ReminderData>();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("GetRemindersToBeSend", conn)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            })
            {
                conn.Open();
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                    {
                        //loop throught the reminders and if the current reminder is send succesfuly delete it ( doesnt work. Why ? )
                        //--------The Part That Puzzles me----------

                        //foreach (var reminder in reminders)
                        //{
                        //    var isSuccessful = false;
                        //    if (((NotificationType)reader["NotificationType"]) == NotificationType.Email)
                        //    {
                        //        isSuccessful = await SendMailMessage(reader["Contact"].ToString(), reader["Title"].ToString(), "Няпомняме за събитие");
                        //    }
                        //    if (((NotificationType)reader["NotificationType"]) == NotificationType.SMS)
                        //    {
                        //        isSuccessful = await SendSmsMessage(reader["Contact"].ToString(), reader["Title"].ToString());
                        //    }
                        //    if (isSuccessful)
                        //    {
                        //        await DeleteReminderAsync((int)reader["ReminderID"], command);
                        //    }
                        //}
                        ReminderData reminder = new ReminderData()
                        {
                            Contact = reader["Contact"].ToString(),
                            NotificationType = (NotificationType)reader["NotificationType"],
                            ReminderID = (int)reader["ReminderID"],
                            Title = reader["Title"].ToString()
                        };
                        reminders.Add(reminder);
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
                //
                StringBuilder whereClause = new StringBuilder();
                //
                foreach (var reminder in reminders)
                {

                    var isSuccessful = false;
                    if (reminder.NotificationType == NotificationType.Email)
                    {
                        isSuccessful = await SendMailMessage(reminder.Contact, reminder.Title, "Няпомняме за събитие");
                    }
                    if (reminder.NotificationType == NotificationType.SMS)
                    {
                        isSuccessful = await SendSmsMessage(reminder.Contact, reminder.Title);
                    }
                    if (isSuccessful)
                    {
                        //whereClause.Append("ReminderID = " + reminder.ReminderID + " & "); //Creating where clause to use for deletion on one hit -- Why not working ?
                        await DeleteReminderAsync(reminder.ReminderID, command);
                    }
                }
                //await DeleteRemindersAsync(whereClause.ToString(), command); // Query for delete many rows of table -- Why not working ?
            }
        }
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    private async Task<bool> DeleteReminderAsync(int id, SqlCommand procedure)
    {
        try
        {
            procedure.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            procedure.CommandText = "RemoveReminder";
            procedure.Parameters.Add("@reminderID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
            await procedure.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> DeleteRemindersAsync(string whereClause, SqlCommand procedure)
    {
        try
        {
            procedure.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            procedure.CommandText = "Delete from Reminders Where " + whereClause.TrimEnd('&',' ','\n','\r');
            await procedure.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    private async Task<bool> SendMailMessage(string SendTo/*, string From*/, string Subject, string Body/*, string EmailHost, int EmailPort, string EmailUserName, string EmailPassword, bool isEmailSsl, bool UseDefaultCredentials = false*/)
    {
        var Creadentials = new NetworkCredential(Dts.Variables["$Package::EmailUserName"].Value.ToString(), Dts.Variables["$Package::EmailPassword"].Value.ToString());
        int smtpServerPort = int.Parse(Dts.Variables["$Package::EmailPort"].Value.ToString());
        String SmtpServer = Dts.Connections["GmailSMTP"].Properties["SmtpServer"].GetValue(Dts.Connections["GmailSMTP"]).ToString();
        try
        {
            using (SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient(SmtpServer, smtpServerPort)
            {
                Credentials = Creadentials,
                EnableSsl = true
            })
            {
                using (MailMessage htmlMessage = new MailMessage(Creadentials.UserName, SendTo, Subject, Body) { IsBodyHtml = true })
                {
                    await mySmtpClient.SendMailAsync(htmlMessage);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private async Task<bool> SendSmsMessage(string SendTo, string Subject, string Encoding = "utf-8")
    {
        string testSms = @"https://bsms.voicecom.bg/smsapi/bsms/sendsms/?sid=1772&id=" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "&msisdn=" + SendTo + "&encoding=" + Encoding + "&text=" + Subject;

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(testSms);
        WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string urlResultText = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

        return urlResultText == "SEND_OK";
    }

    class ReminderData
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int ReminderID { get; set; }
        public NotificationType NotificationType { get; set; }
        public string Contact { get; set; }
    }

    enum NotificationType
    {
        SMS = 0,
        Email = 1
    }
```

on the other hand i decided to generete a where clause to delete all reminders which are sended succesfuly but that doesnt seem to work too. 
What am i doing wrong

Comment: The not commented code works well.

Comment: What happens when you debug the foreach loop for reminders?

Comment: Actualy i've just made it work the problem there was that i was using '&' instead of 'OR'

Comment: i am storing in the where clause :
ex. ReminderID = 1 Or ReminderID = 2 Or ReminderID = 3 Or 1=0

thats the thing i just fixed,
But i'm still wandering why i cant deal with everything in the reader loop

Comment: The Delete call in the top loop doesn't do the string manipulation, why would that work? if you have no where clause, the SQL still says where, that's a syntax issue.

Comment: Actualy i have two Delete function one accepts (reminderId, command) the other (whereClause, command)

Comment: @JacobH on the first async action the control is returned and sqldumper.exe pops up